# Trouble with ggplot2 position = "fill"

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am having trouble with creating a `position = "fill"` graph and was wondering where I was going wrong.  I found some data from a wikipedia page and created a dataframe out of it:

```
#Vitamin Contents in %DV of common cheeses per 100gm
Cheese <- c("Swiss", "Feta", "Cheddar","Mozarella", "Cottage")
A <- c(17, 8, 20, 14, 3)
B1 <- c(4, 10, 2, 2, 2)
B2 <- c(17, 50, 22, 17,10)
B3 <- c(0,5,0,1,0)
B5 <- c(4, 10, 4, 1, 6)Rplot
B6 <- c(4, 21, 4, 2, 2)
B9 <- c(1, 8, 5, 2, 3)
B12 <- c(56, 28, 14, 38, 7)
Ch <- c(2.8, 2.2, 3, 2.8, 3.3)
C <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
D <- c(11, 0, 3, 0, 0)
E <- c(2, 1, 1, 1, 0)

Cheese_Vitamins <- data.frame(Cheese, A, B1, B2, B3, B5, B6, B9, B12, Ch, C, D, E)
```

I then converted the data.frame from a wide to long format using the `gather` function from the `tidyr` package`:

```
long.cheese.vit <- gather(Cheese_Vitamins, Vitamins, Percentage, c(A, B1, B2, B3, B5, B6, B9, B12,Ch, C, D, E))
```

However when I try to graph a filled chart:

```
ggplot(long.cheese.vit, aes(Cheese, fill = Percentage)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill")
```

I don't get the result that I am looking for:

[image: Cheese Vitamin content]

What I am trying to create is a filled bargraph with the vitamin content broken down by percentage for each cheese.
Any suggestions would be helpful.
Thank you!

Comment: A small correction: `gather()` is a `tidyr` function.

Comment: Your percentages per cheese group don't add up to 100%, is this intended?

Comment: @ccapizzano makes a good point. The values are percentage of daily value per vitamin, so filling to 100% is not appropriate here.

Comment: @neilfws Thank you for the clarification, I will adjust my answer if it is no longer suitable.

Comment: You were trying to plot something else but just for the record. If you use `fill = factor(percentage)` you will get different colors for different percentages. Variable `fill` in `ggplot` takes `factors` not `numeric` variables.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The values for each vitamin are percentages of daily value, per vitamin. So it is not appropriate to stack the values, or to fill them as proportions of 100%.

One option is to fill by vitamin but to dodge the bars. I'm using `rvest` to grab the data straight from the Wikipedia table:

```
library(rvest)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese#Nutrition_and_health") %>%
  html_node("#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(98)") %>% 
  html_table() %>%
  gather(vitamin, percentage, -Cheese) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Cheese, percentage)) + 
    geom_col(aes(fill = vitamin), position = "dodge")
```

[image]

This is OK but with 13 vitamins, the colours become difficult to distinguish. A better option might be to use facets for the vitamins.

```
read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese#Nutrition_and_health") %>%
  html_node("#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(98)") %>% 
  html_table() %>%
  gather(vitamin, percentage, -Cheese) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Cheese, percentage)) + 
    geom_col() + 
    facet_grid(vitamin ~ .)
```

[image]

You might also consider reversing the facets using `facet_grid(. ~ vitamin)`, that results in rather cluttered x-axis labels but makes vitamin comparison easier. So perhaps fill by cheese and remove the labels:

```
read_html("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cheese#Nutrition_and_health") %>%
  html_node("#mw-content-text > div > table:nth-child(98)") %>% 
  html_table() %>%
  gather(vitamin, percentage, -Cheese) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Cheese, percentage)) + 
    geom_col(aes(fill = Cheese)) + 
    facet_grid(. ~ vitamin) + 
    theme(axis.text.x = element_blank())
```

[image]

Comment: One of the best answers on any r plot ever. +1

Comment: Hi Neil, I have one more question that I was wondering if you could help me with?  I have been trying to figure out how to use code to determine which cheese provides the most of each vitamin.  For instance, with these graphs I can see that Swiss cheese provides the most vitamin B12, but how do I use code to determine this for all vitamins?  

I am also a big fan of your blog.  Thank you for all your help

Comment: I'd normally suggest posting a new question, but this should work. Code as in the answer, but then the gather is: `gather(vitamin, percentage,-Cheese) %>% group_by(vitamin, Cheese) %>% summarise(v = max(percentage)) %>% filter(v == max(v))`. Note there will be ties: for example, no cheeses contain vitamin C, so all five will be listed with value = 0.

Answer (score 1):

You need to properly identify the `Percentage` column as a y value and use the `stat` argument in `geom_bar` (not `position`). Yet, your percentages per cheese group don't add up to 100% so I will update my answer once I know more...

```
ggplot(long.cheese.vit, aes(x=Cheese,y=Percentage,fill=Vitamins)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

[image]